# Grab Instagram Follower count without Authentication

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

Anyway to get profile follower count without authentication? I can't find any function for this in the basic display api or graph api.

Answer (score 0):

you can use
https://www.instagram.com/XXXXXX/?__a=1
for ex
https://www.instagram.com/instagram/?__a=1
it return a json , you can parse it to your model . and follower count is under
graphql.user.edge_follow.count

if you cant see json,then you most use a valid proxies to bypass instagram login page